# How to verify parent.parent.id in a tree structure?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, h2

[image]

How do I create a proper SQL select which does the following:

```
Select * 
From Parameter_NODE
Where name=test112 AND parent_id=1 AND parent.parent_id=null;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to self-join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM parameter_node AS p
   JOIN parameter_node AS p_parent
      ON p.parent_id = p_parent.id
WHERE p.name = 'test112'
  AND p.parent_id = 1
  AND p_parent.parent_id IS NULL;
```

Other things that were wrong in your query:

- string constants must be surrounded by single quotes
- you cannot use `=` to test for NULL-ness, you have to use `IS NULL`

Comment: Can you have a look into the question bellow? Thanks!